# Битрикс присылает нечитаемое сообщение о выполненном заказе

Tags: битрикс

Столкнулся с проблемой, что готовое предложение, которое мне сделали аспро, имеет некоторые косяки.

Сижу второй день, не могу его доработать под себя. Помогите плиз.

Проблема в том, что когда кто-то делает заказ на сайте, то сообщение, которое приходит на емейл о том, что сделан заказ, содержит поле с подробностями о заказе, содержащее название элемента. А нужно, чтобы содержало помимо названия элемента также название раздела и подраздела. Как это можно сделать? Обьясню - у нас много позиций и когда делается заказ чего-либо, то пишется просто 30х34 (к примеру), а ты думай, к какому разделу это относится... Подскажите пожалуйста. Ниже представлены скриншоты - то, как это выглядит, когда кто-то делает заказ. Настройки, которые возможно что-то могут поменять... Помогите пожалуйста...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="maxwidth-theme">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form order<?=($arResult['isFormNote'] == 'Y' ? ' success' : '')?><?=($arResult['isFormErrors'] == 'Y' ? ' error' : '')?>">
    <?=$arResult["FORM_HEADER"]?>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
       <?if( $arResult["isIblockDescription"] ){?>
        <div class="description">
         <?if( $arResult["IBLOCK_DESCRIPTION_TYPE"] == "text" ){?>
          <p><?=$arResult["IBLOCK_DESCRIPTION"]?></p>
         <?}else{?>
          <?=$arResult["IBLOCK_DESCRIPTION"]?>
         <?}?>
        </div>
       <?}?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
       <div class="row">
        <?if($arResult['isFormErrors'] == 'Y'):?>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-error alert alert-danger">
           <?=$arResult['FORM_ERRORS_TEXT']?>
          </div>
         </div>
        <?endif;?>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
         <?if(is_array($arResult["QUESTIONS"])):?>
          <?foreach( $arResult["QUESTIONS"] as $FIELD_SID => $arQuestion ){
           if( $FIELD_SID == "MESSAGE" ) continue;
           if( $arQuestion['STRUCTURE'][0]['FIELD_TYPE'] == 'hidden' ){
            echo $arQuestion["HTML_CODE"];
           }else{?>
            <?$hidden = ($FIELD_SID == 'ORDER_LIST' || $FIELD_SID == 'SESSION_ID');?>
            <div class="row<?=($hidden ? ' hidden' : '');?>" data-SID="<?=$FIELD_SID?>">
             <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
               <?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?>
               <div class="input">
                <?=$arQuestion["HTML_CODE"]?>
               </div>
               <?if( !empty( $arQuestion["HINT"] ) ){?>
                <div class="hint"><?=$arQuestion["HINT"]?></div>
               <?}?>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           <?}
          }?>
         <?endif;?>
        </div>
        <?if($arResult["QUESTIONS"]["MESSAGE"]):?>
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="row" data-SID="MESSAGE">
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <?=$arResult["QUESTIONS"]["MESSAGE"]["CAPTION"]?>
             <div class="input">
              <?=$arResult["QUESTIONS"]["MESSAGE"]["HTML_CODE"]?>
             </div>
             <?if( !empty( $arResult["QUESTIONS"]["MESSAGE"]["HINT"] ) ){?>
              <div class="hint"><?=$arResult["QUESTIONS"]["MESSAGE"]["HINT"]?></div>
             <?}?>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <?endif;?>
        <?if($arResult["isUseCaptcha"] === "Y"):?>
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="row <?=($arResult["isUseReCaptcha"] === 'Y' ? 'recaptcha-row' : 'captcha-row')?>">
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <?=$arResult["CAPTCHA_CAPTION"]?>
             <?if($arResult["isUseReCaptcha"] === "Y"):?>
              <div class="input <?=($arResult['CAPTCHA_ERROR'] == 'Y' ? 'error' : '')?>">
               <input type="hidden" class="recaptcha" name="recaptcha" id="recaptcha">
               <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?=RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY?>" data-callback="reCaptchaVerify" data-theme="light" data-size="normal"></div>
              </div>
             <?else:?>
              <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <?=$arResult["CAPTCHA_IMAGE"]?>
                <span class="refresh"><a href="javascript:;" rel="nofollow"><?=GetMessage("REFRESH")?></a></span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="input <?=($arResult['CAPTCHA_ERROR'] == 'Y' ? 'error' : '')?>">
                 <?=$arResult["CAPTCHA_FIELD"]?>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
             <?endif;?>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <?endif;?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PROCESSING_NOTE"] === "Y"):?>
         <div class="processing-block">
          <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input">
             <input type="checkbox" class="processing_approval" id="processing_approval" name="processing_approval" value="Y"<?=($arParams["PROCESSING_NOTE_CHECKED"] === 'Y' ? ' checked' : '')?>>
             <label for="processing_approval"><?$APPLICATION->IncludeFile(SITE_DIR."include/processing_note.php", Array(), Array("MODE" => "html"))?></label>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <?endif;?>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 26px;">
         <div class="pull-right required-fileds">
          <i class="star">*</i><?=GetMessage("FORM_REQUIRED_FILEDS")?>
         </div>
         <div class="pull-left">
          <?=str_replace('class="', 'class="btn-lg ', $arResult["SUBMIT_BUTTON"])?>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <?=$arResult["FORM_FOOTER"]?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 if(arScorpOptions['THEME']['USE_CAPTCHA_FORM'] == 'RECAPTCHA'){
  reCaptchaRender();
 }

 if(arScorpOptions['THEME']['USE_SALE_GOALS'] !== 'N'){
  var eventdata = {goal: 'goal_order_begin'};
  BX.onCustomEvent('onCounterGoals', [eventdata]);
 }

 $('.order.form form[name="<?=$arResult["IBLOCK_CODE"]?>"]').validate({
  ignore: ".ignore",
  highlight: function( element ){
   $(element).parent().addClass('error');
  },
  unhighlight: function( element ){
   $(element).parent().removeClass('error');
  },
  submitHandler: function( form ){
   if( $('.order.form form[name="<?=$arResult["IBLOCK_CODE"]?>"]').valid() ){
    $(form).find('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    form.submit();
   }
  },
  errorPlacement: function( error, element ){
   error.insertBefore(element);
  }
 });

 if(arScorpOptions['THEME']['PHONE_MASK'].length){
  var base_mask = arScorpOptions['THEME']['PHONE_MASK'].replace( /(\d)/g, '_' );
  $('.order.form form[name="<?=$arResult["IBLOCK_CODE"]?>"] input.phone').inputmask("mask", { "mask": arScorpOptions['THEME']['PHONE_MASK'] });
  $('.order.form form[name="<?=$arResult["IBLOCK_CODE"]?>"] input.phone').blur(function(){
   if( $(this).val() == base_mask || $(this).val() == '' ){
    if( $(this).hasClass('required') ){
     $(this).parent().find('div.error').html(BX.message("JS_REQUIRED"));
    }
   }
  });
 }

 var sessionID = '<?=bitrix_sessid()?>';
 $('input#SESSION_ID').val(sessionID);

 $('.order.form form[name="<?=$arResult["IBLOCK_CODE"]?>"] input.date').inputmask(arScorpOptions['THEME']['DATE_MASK'], { 'placeholder': arScorpOptions['THEME']['DATE_PLACEHOLDER'] });
 $('.order.form form[name="<?=$arResult["IBLOCK_CODE"]?>"] input.datetime').inputmask(arScorpOptions['THEME']['DATETIME_MASK'], { 'placeholder': arScorpOptions['THEME']['DATETIME_PLACEHOLDER'] });

 $("input[type=file]").uniform({ fileButtonHtml: BX.message("JS_FILE_BUTTON_NAME"), fileDefaultHtml: BX.message("JS_FILE_DEFAULT") });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Так представляются домены с не ASCII символами (та же кириллица), оно при этом будет рабочим. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name А где именно заполняется та ссылка в `Ссылка на форму`?

Comment: @gil9red она генерируется автоматически, если по ней перейти, то попадаешь в битрикс админ панель, где показывается ИД товара. Это проблема.... Уже весь мозг себе того самое, второй день думаю и не понимаю, разные настройки перепробовал(. Откуда оно идёт попробую найти сейчас...

Comment: всё еще актуально....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поля в почтовый шаблон добавляются программно. Если вы не программист, то лучше найдите программиста 1c-bitrix, потому что добавление полей в почтовый шаблон требует знаний программирования в CMS 1c-bitrix, если вы программист то добавляются поля как в этой статье https://admin4web.ru/article/svoi-polya-zakaza-v-pochtovom-shablone-bitriks/ по событию OnOrderNewSendEmail. Так же вам надо получить разделы товара, который есть в заказе c помощью CIBlockElement::GetList либо  CIBlockElement::GetIBlockByID